# sqlite3 add row to table doesnt add no errors

Tags: python, database, sqlite, python-3.6

I have an SQLite3 database that I want to add to with python, this is the code i have to add a row

```py
def create_connection(db_file):
    """ create a database connection to a SQLite database """
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        return conn
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

def add_password(conn, data):
    """
    Create an entry into the password database
    """
    try:
        sql = 'INSERT INTO passwords(added,username,password,website,email) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)'
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(sql, data)
        print('done')
        return cur.lastrowid
    except Error as e:
        print(e)

connection = create_connection('passwords.db')

data = (datetime.now(), 'SomeUsername', 'password123', 'stackoverflow.com', 'some@email.com')
add_password(connection, data)
```

When I run it prints `done` and ends, there are no errors. However, when I open the database to view the table, it has no entries.

If I open the database and run the same SQL code

```sql
INSERT INTO passwords(added,username,password,website,email) 
VALUES('13-5-2020', 'SomeUsername', 'password123', 'stackoverflow.com', 'some@email.com')
```

it adds to the table. So it must be a problem with my python code. How do I get it to add?

Comment: Depending if you are on auto-commit mode or not you will have to send a `COMMIT`.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is on auto-commit, how do I check this @KlausD.

Comment: `connection.isolation_level` is `None` in autocommit mode. You can also set it to use that mode.

Comment: It is set to none, so i need to add a `conn.commit()`? and what would i set it to to enable it? `True`? @MichaelButscher

Comment: No, it is in autocommit mode. The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection.isolation_level) explain it in full detail.

Comment: If you are running a modifying query (like `INSERT`) sqlite will open an implicit transaction by default. Run `conn.commit()` to apply the changes. This increases performance and integrity and is generally a good practice.

Comment: @KlausD. The point of autocommit mode is that the `commit()` isn't necessary for a modifying query.

Comment: `"None for autocommit mode"` this implies that if it is `None` it will auto-commit, however, it is the opposite for me @MichaelButscher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `conn.commit()` after executing query. It should work